# Rails Active Resource with sunspot solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource, sunspot-solr

Hello i"m trying to implement an app which draws its contents via Active Resource, but i'd like to be able to search these contents. is it possible to use sunspot solr with active resource?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Follow the approach outlined on my blog at http://www.chandranshu.com/sunspot-with-activeresource/ .

The critical part is to create an InstanceAdapter and a DataAccessor and include them into your ActiveResource model. Rest all you can figure out from the errors that you get.